# Unable to login magento administration

Tags: php, magento, authentication

I have just installed Magento on Windows using WAMP.

Installation was successfull without any errors or warnings.

When i browse administration page, i can see login screen.  After entering the correct credentials it is not displaying me the Dashboard/Control Panel.  Its displaying the same login page.

If i enter wrong credentials, its authenticating and displaying a message as "invalid username or password"

I am unable to determine the issue.  If anybody has been through this issue and solved it please help me.

How can i login Magento administration.

Note: While installation i have selected session=Database.  Will that be a issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a common issue w/ Magento installations, and the most common cause of it is actually the domain from which you access the site. If you are accessing the site locally, using the "site" `http://localhost/` seems to cause this issue. Adding a host to your hosts file to map another domain to localhost (`http://localhost.local` worked for me) may enable you to log in.

To be sure, this is not a database issue, but an issue having to do with your webserver.

Hope that helps. Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Thanks for your response joe.  
But i am running my webserver(apache) on localhost:8888
I am browsing http://localhost:8888/magento.com/admin

if i try your way then how should it be http://localhost:8888.local/magento.com/admin  

is it the way shall I browse?

Thanks
SIA

Comment: What you're changing is the domain name. "localhost" is actually a domain in the same way that "google.com" is. You would be accessing the domain as http://localhost.local:8888/magento.com/admin

Comment: Also, on a side note, make sure that you change the base URLs in the system to reflect this as well.

Comment: Joe is right about this.  You have two options.  The first is to use a made up host name that you put in your hosts file (for example, http://www.localhost.com/magento, which is made up).  The second option is to simply use your localhost ip address, 127.0.0.1 rather than localhost.  The core problem with using only "localhost" is that cookies don't work without a "valid" domain name (ie, a host name with a dot "." in it). 
This link helped to clarify for me: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/4337/P30/#t163802

Answer (score 0):

This is about Magento's set_cookie_params in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php:100 - if you comment out ssl_only param from this function call - this error will stop to appear. but don't forget to comment it back in production:)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but there is not ssl_only parameter on line 100 in that function.

code : call_user_func_array('session_set_cookie_params', $cookieParams);

and in $cookieParams Array the code is <br />

        // session cookie params
        $cookieParams = array(
            'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
            'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
            'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
           // 'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),  
            'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
        );

I tried this but no luck. Anything else.